# Symfony Form handle one-to-many as one-to-one

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

In the database the relation between contact and contactAddress is a one-to-many.

I want to handle a symfony form and not use the collection type because it should be a one-to-one for the user.

```
$builder->add(
    'contactAddresses',
    new ContactAddressType()
);
```

Following error appears:

> Neither the property "contactAddresses" nor one of the methods
>   "addContactAddress()"/"removeContactAddress()",
>   "setContactAddresses()", "contactAddresses()", "__set()" or "__call()"
>   exist and have public access in class
>   "My\Bundle\ContactBundle\Entity\Contact".

The `addContactAddress` method exist in my contact entity.

```
public function addContactAddress(ContactAddress $contactAddress)
{
    $this->contactAddresses[] = $contactAddress;

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$builder
    ->add('contactAddresses','entity', array(
        'class'=>'yourBundle:ContactAddress',
        'property'=>'propertyToDisplay'
    ));
```

Comment: entity is a choice i need to render an own sub formType which own fields.

Answer (score 0):

Did fix it by use CollectionType and add a $contactAddress to it

Builder:

```
$builder->add(
    'contactAddresses',
    'collection', [
        'entity' => new ContactTypeAddress()
    ]
);
```

Controller:

```
$contact = new Contact();
$contact->addContactAddress(new ContactAddress()); // This line did fix my problem

$this->createForm(new MyContactType(), $contact);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add it as follows:

```
$builder->add('contactAddresses',ContactAddressType()::class);
```